# Why would an answer come up in the review que long after being posted?

Tags: support

I came across an answer in the review que that was flagged as low quality, normal enough except that it was 3 years old.

here is the link: https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/199833

The only reason I can come up with is that it was either missed somehow by the Community, or that it was flagged but that the reviewer at the time let it pass.  If the later I suspect that the fact that there was a recent comment made it appear back in the review que again as it matched the heuristics of a low quality question.

Am I correct here or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think the review system even existed three years ago, so that would explain it still being around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it's possible that someone manually flagged the answer as VLQ, and that caused it to pop into the VLQ queue.

If I remember correctly, manual flags do that as part of the overhaul flags got.

Comment: Yes, I do belive that you are right, I seem to remember reading that now that you mentioned it....never occurred to me.  Most likely the same user that commented(comment was please expand you answer instead of just including a link) likely flagged it as well.....

Comment: @TrailRider some references http://meta.superuser.com/q/7338/235569

Comment: @Braiam Thank you